# C# How to store a variable stored in side for loop or for each to out side variable

Tags: c#

I want to store a variable inside for loop or foreach into variables outside of the function.

```
Class User{ 
   public int password;
   public int[] user_password;
   public static int[] Password = new int[40];
   int counter = 0;

   public void register(){

        Console.WriteLine("Enter member's password?");
        int password = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Password[counter] = password;

        counter++;

        for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
           user_password[i] = Password[i];
        }             
   }

   public int getpassword(){
      return user_password[];
   }

}
```

what I wanna do here, is that I want to store all value of Passwordrarray into a new array called `user_password`, and then want to call getpassword function in other class.
However, the code above do not store anything inside `user_password` array, and it just only return null.

How should I deal with this problem? Do I need to consider using get set?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understood what you are trying to achieve. Is the issue in `register` or `getpassword`? Is the missing index in  `user_password[];` a typo? Do you mean `user_password[counter];` or `public getpassword(int index){
      return user_password[index];
   }`

Comment: The password here is an int array? Is that normal? Does an `User` have multiple password or is this class representing an user having a property that strore the password of every other users?

Comment: Frankely, I want to return all passwords using getpassword().

Comment: But the code above does not return any value,

Comment: `public getpassword(){
      return user_password[];
   }`  is missing the **return type** you means `public int[] getpassword(){
      return user_password;
   }` and Yes you can use a Getter or `User.Password`. But a specific user beeing able to return all the password look like a bad idea. It's not about security but functionality.

Comment: There are so many issues with your code I don't know where to start. Maybe you could explain what you're trying to do with this code? When explaining don't refer at all to your code, just the requirement you're trying to solve.

Comment: oh I know, for int I just forgot to type sorry, but I meant I want user_password to get the value of Password array, it seems I cannot access to value that is in for loop.
I don't know why.

Comment: You cannot assigne a value to `user_password[i]` in the for loop because it's not initilised. as the `System.NullReferenceException` told you. The error message should be "you can not assign a value to an unassigned".

Answer (score 0):

Not considering security issues here of just saving passwords like this but consider using a Dictionary. Something like this (you will have to adapt to your reality):

```
Dictionary<string, string> userPsw = Dictionary<string, string>();
```

To save a new one:

```
if (!userPsw.ContainsKey("my_user"))
    userPsw.Add("my_user", "my_password");
```

To get an existing one:

```
return userPsw["my_user"];
```

Or even:

```
userPsw.TryGetValue("my_user", out value);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I can't really use any other than array.